# Unable to connect to gitlab

Tags: git, ssh

Okay, so my school's CS program is using gitlab for projects.

First thing I had to do was generate an SSH key and add it to my gitlab profile.  They gave directions to generate it, like so:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$your_email"
```

Presumably, I should change "$your_email" to say, "keirathi@mymail.com"?  Anyways, it generated a key and I put that in my gitlab profile.  I assume it worked correctly because it accepted the key and shows me a footprint that matches the footprint I got when I generated the SSH key file.

Next step, I created a project on gitlab.  It gives me some directions for creating a local git repository and pushing it to the server.

```
git config --global user.name "MyFirst Middle LastName"
git config --global user.email "keirathi@mymail.com"

mkdir homeworks2125
cd homeworks2125
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@gitlab.cs.myschool.edu:myUserName/homeworks2125.git
git push -u origin master
```

But, whenever I try to push, I just get:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

This is driving me crazy because I've never had this kind of authorization trouble using git before with github or anything.

I'm sure there's something wrong with the ssh key, but I'm not sure what.  Any help?

Edit: not sure if this is relevant info, but here's what happens if I run "ssh -vvv git@gitlab.cs.myschool.edu"

```
G:\homeworks2125 [master]> ssh -vvv git@gitlab.cs.uno.edu
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.cs.uno.edu [137.30.120.92] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Jonathan/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /c/Users/Jonathan/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Jonathan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Jonathan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with your key generation.

`Not a RSA1 key file` is a really strong message.

In [SSH Error: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'](https://serverfault.com/questions/506092/ssh-error-unknown-key-type-begin) they suggest using the `ssh-keygen` command to properly convert your key - but you can simply generate a new one.